# Connect with sftp client to server that can be accessed only through other server

Tags: ssh-tunnel, tunneling, nx

I am new to this forum and to this kind of stuff so don't judge me hard:

I would like to connect with:
sftp client (Bitise Tunneler) and nxClient (NOMACHINE)
to the server A through other server B. Because server B is reachable from my computer and A is not.

I understood that I need some kind of tunneling. But don't know how to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The following SSH config in `~/.ssh/config` allows you to easily setup tunnels. It requires `nc` to be installed on the intermediate host.

```
Host *%*
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f2-) nc $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f1) %p
```

Running `ssh host1.example.com%host2.example.com` will SSH to host1 via host2.  I don't know whether your SFTP client will use this configuration though. In that case you can manually setup a tunnel for it to use with something like the following:

```
ssh -fNL 10022:host1.example.com:22 host2.example.com
```

and then configure the SFTP client to connect to `localhost:10022`.

Comment: nice config example! I am sure I will find a use for that.